# Markup formatting during keyboard input depending on template

Tags: emacs, elisp

I would like to create an Emacs-mode that behaves the following way:

When starting a new paragraph, Emacs asks in a buffer window, which
template to use:

```
buffer window:
1 - standard (default)
2 - person
3 - insertion
4 - location
5 - header

Just <ENTER> selects 1 - standard (default).
```

Whenever two captital letters are put in, everything till the next space
or line ending should be in capitals:

```
PErson -> PERSON

PErson NAmed CHuck -> PERSON NAMED CHUCK
```

The standard-template works something like this:

A standard paragraph starts with a person. After the person, there may or
may not follow some ():

If (), then follows a line break:

```
input (note the missing <SPACE>):
PErson(doing something).bla bla bla.

output:
PERSON <i>(doing something)</i>.
bla bla bla.
```

If no ():

```
input:
PErson.bla bla bla.

output:
PERSON. bla bla bla.
```

For demonstrating what should happen depending on the chosen template,
here are some sample inputs:

```
Choose "1 - standard" + input:
PErson(doing something. Something else. Something else).bla bla
bla<ENTER>bla bla bla<ENTER>bla bla bla.<ENTER><ENTER>

should become:

output:
<standard>PERSON <i>(doing something. Something else. Something else)</i>.
bla bla bla
bla bla bla
bla bla bla.</standard>
```

---

```
Choose "2 - person" + input:
Description of a place. PErson NAmed CHuck walks around the corner.<ENTER>

output:
<person><i>Description of a place.</i> PERSON NAMED CHUCK <i>walks around
the corner.</i></person>
```

---

```
Choose "3 - insertion" + input:
Something happens. Something can be heard. Something can be seen.<ENTER>

output:
<insertion><i>(Something happens. Something can be heard. Something can be
seen.)</i></insertion>

Note:
Depending on the selected template, a paragraph ends with <ENTER> or
<ENTER><ENTER>.
```

The final markup file (html, xml, whatever) should be used in LibreOffice
for further processing.

I already wrote an Emacs mode some time ago. Very simple thing. But with
this here, I would be grateful for every hint you can offer.

Comment: You're asking quite a lot of questions here. If you still want to write your own mode, it's likely a better idea to break this up into several specific questions. If you just want to write a screenplay, have a look at my answer below.

Comment: Also found screenplay.el and can definitley use something of it when it comes to formatting. Wanted to give you an upvote but still have too few reputation, sorry. :) What I'm really aiming for is not to have to put in markup. It's more about creating markup without writing it.

Comment: I haven't used `fountain-mode`, but it looks like it [automates quite a lot of that for you](https://github.com/rnkn/fountain-mode/blob/master/fountain-mode.el#L2189). For example, `C-c C-m` and `S-RET` are both bound to `fountain-upcase-line-and-newline`, which in turn uppercases the entire current line and inserts a newline. So typing `person (doing something)` followed by `S-RET` would give you what it seems you want. It's just a matter of trying it out and seeing what needs improvement.

Comment: atm I'm looking to get it running without using any pre-inputs to select a template. Most times I only use three templates and after inputting two chars it should be clear which one to use at the latest (one template starts with two capitals, one with a "(" and the last with one capital. I strive to avoid any key-combinations except using <SHIFT>. Just keeping hands on the letters and hack. No C-M-something-wrenching, no navigating back to mark or format something in the paragraph, just typing on and on and on from left to right till the end. :)

Comment: Hey @hackwriter (I'm sure you're not a hack). I can see it's not what you're after, but I'm the creator/maintainer of `fountain-mode`. `C-m` is effectively the same as `RET`, it's just used in the code because some terminals don't read `<return>` the same way, so `C-c C-m` is effectively `C-c RET` (as an alternative to `S-RET` which can't be read in terminal mode). n.b. All of this may be different on Windows though.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you're trying to write a mode for screenwriting.

Instead of writing your own, maybe give [Fountain Mode](https://github.com/rnkn/fountain-mode/) a shot:

> Fountain Mode aims to be a full-featured screenwriting environment for GNU Emacs using the Fountain markup format. For more information on the Fountain markup format, visit http://fountain.io.

Fountain Mode can be installed via [MELPA](https://melpa.org/#/fountain-mode) or [MELPA stable](https://stable.melpa.org/#/fountain-mode). Here's a screenshot from its GitHub page:

[image]
<sub>(source: [paulwrankin.com](http://files.paulwrankin.com/fountain-mode/screenshot.png))</sub>